# Wifi radio with an Arduino

Tags: wifi, audio, networking

I've done a Wifi radio with a headless Raspberry Pi in the past (connecting a radio MP3 stream available on internet directly on boot, without any user input), and now I'm wondering: would it be possible to do the same with an Arduino, battery-powered?

Please correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that all these features are available:

1. battery-powered: this is definitely possible with a few AAs
2. audio output (easily possible with a DAC I think?)
3. Wifi (possible with a shield, right?)
4. Internet access to http://198.51.100.0/myradio.mp3 stream
5. real-ime MP3 stream decoding (Is an Atmega enough for this?)

**Does this mean that a Wifi radio based on Arduino is possible?**

Comment: `real-ime MP3 stream decoding (Is an Atmega enough for this?)` -- Certainly not, no.  I have managed it with a 200MHz PIC32. I wouldn't even begin to consider doing it with a tiny 8-bit MCU...

Comment: @Majenko I looked at ESP8266, and [it *seems* possible](https://github.com/espressif/esp8266_mp3_decoder). Is this really true, or do you think it relies on additional hardware chip?

Comment: Have you read the readme?

Comment: After re-reading now, yes it seems it's possible without any other chip, but not recommended (RAM is a plus for buffering and DAC for better output quality)

Comment: I have/had a wifi radio in the OpenWRT part of a Arduino Yún. OpenWRT is a minimal linux. For software decoding, I strongly advise to use some kind of linux computer, because they already have packages for mp3 decoding. There are Arduino projects using the VS1053 as a hardware MP3 decoder. An Arduino board with Ethernet Shield uses a lot of power, that is not something for a battery. What about an ESP32 with a hardware MP3 decoder ?

Comment: There are many types of Arduino boards (reads: many different platforms and processors) and many Arduino hardware add-ons.  If you spend enough, eventually you may find a platform and / or hardware combination capable of supporting your feature list.  However, it is likely the RaspberryPi will be able to support your feature list for far less money.  Certainly in much less time and effort.

Comment: if the ESP8266 looks possible, the ESP32 should be a lot better, what with it's dual-core and all...